# PHP Creating PHPUNIT.XML file

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the PHP unit and its working fine.Now i want to write the testcases through PHPStorm IDE.To build/run the testcases using PHPStorm it requires config file(phpunit.xml)

so can anyone tell what are the contents of PHPunit.xml.
It would be great if you can provide me a sample PHPUnit.xml file and let me know where it should be placed.(if any particular folder structure)

Comment: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Comment: It doesn't require. You can run tests just fine in phphstorm without phpunit.xml (as i do).

Comment: For authoring the XML file, you might be interested in https://github.com/gooh/phpunit-schema

Answer (score 4):

Documentation: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration

Explanation in JetBrains blog: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/webide/2009/12/phpunit-support/

And you can get help from community: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5275424#5275424

Comment: Documentation link for phpunit.de, no longer works. Updated to [http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration)

Answer (score 4):

for new users see this post,
you can use this command to generate simple `phpunit.xml` file

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --generate-configuration
```